# I need help getting the first n characters of a string up to when a number character starts

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm working with a string where I need to extract the first n characters up to where numbers begin. What would be the best way to do this as sometimes the string starts with a number: `7EUSA8889er898` I would need to extract `7EUSA` But other string examples would be `SWFX74849948`, I would need to extract `SWFX` from that string.

Not sure how to do this with regex my limited knowledge is blocking me at this point:

`^(\w{4})` that just gets me the first four characters but I don't really have a stopping point as sometimes the string could be `somelongstring292894830982` which would require me to get `somelongstring`

Comment: To clarify: You want all of the characters up until the first occurrence of a number? But if the first character is a number you should go until the next number? What if the first 2 or 3 characters are all numbers?

Comment: Yeah, only the first character would be a number. But it would have to go up until the next character is a number.

Comment: So this would be invalid: `78werere787979`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `\w` will match a word character which includes characters and digits and an underscore.

You could match an optional digit `[0-9]?` from the start of the string `^`and then match 1+ times A-Za-z

```
^[0-9]?[A-Za-z]+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Xlogcb/1)

```js
const regex = /^[0-9]?[A-Za-z]+/;
[
  "7EUSA8889er898",
  "somelongstring292894830982",
  "SWFX74849948"
].forEach(s => console.log(s.match(regex)[0]));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Can use this regex code:

```
(^\d+?[a-zA-Z]+)|(^\d+|[a-zA-Z]+)
```

I try with exmaple and good worked:

1- somelongstring292894830982 -> somelongstring

2- 7sdfsdf5456 -> 7sdfsdf

3- 875werwer54556 -> 875werwer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create function where the RegExp is parametrized by n parameter, this would be

```
  function getStr(str,n) {
    var pattern = "\\d?\\w{0,"+n+"}";
    var reg = new RegExp(pattern);
    var result = reg.exec(str);
    if(result[0]) return result[0].substr(0,n);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are answers to this but here is another way to do it.

```
var string1 = '7EUSA8889er898';
var string2 = 'SWFX74849948';

var Extract = function (args) {
    var C = args.split(''); // Split string in array
    var NI = []; // Store indexes of all numbers
    // Loop through list -> if char is a number add its index
    C.map(function (I) { return /^\d+$/.test(I) === true ? NI.push(C.indexOf(I)) : ''; });
    // Get the items between the first and second occurence of a number
    return C.slice(NI[0] === 0 ? NI[0] + 1 : 0, NI[1]).join('');
};
console.log(Extract(string1));
console.log(Extract(string2));
```

Output

```
EUSA
SWFX7
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it's hard to tell what you are trying to match, I'd go with a general regex

```
^\d?\D+(?=\d)
```